# Tensorflow lite Error :Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on the classification problem. The dataset is a .csv file that I created myself. Keras model is working and I want to convert the model to tensorflow lite as keras model.

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

the error code is as follows. Where am I making a mistake?

```
WARNING:absl:Function `_wrapped_model` contains input name(s) Mesafe, Derece, Yas, Irk with unsupported characters which will be renamed to mesafe, derece, yas, irk in the SavedModel.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /tmp/tmp70uq2yx2/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /tmp/tmp70uq2yx2/assets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-cdc4a5509c9a> in <module>()
      1 # Convert the model.
      2 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
----> 3 tflite_model = converter.convert()
      4 
      5 # Save the model.

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array.
```

Comment: Could you post, if possible, mor einfo about the model? This porblem exists for layers such as `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962509/valueerror-cannot-convert-a-tensor-of-dtype-resource-to-a-numpy-array/62161525#62161525

Comment: The ones I use are `category_encoding_layer` and `normalization_layer`. I have 4 attributes and I have a column of tags. I have edited the 4 attributes with `category_encoding_layer` and `normalization_layer`. I had 2 floats, 1 string and 1 int feature. I guess the fault is somewhere here. I tried other ways.

Comment: Whata bout if you specify `converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]` before conversion? And also try  `converter.target_spec.supported_ops = []`         `converter.target_spec.supported_ops.append(tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS)`
           `converter.target_spec.supported_ops.append(tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS)`

Comment: I will try. Does tensorflow lite accept attribute columns? I saw a post that seemed unable to convert in another forum.

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean with attribute columns. It should support vectors though.

Comment: Also checks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876823/converting-model-to-tflite-with-select-tf-ops-cannot-convert-ops-hashtablev2-o

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42673